# Why are jQuery source view pages not allowed as hyper-links on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, external-links

Why are jQuery source view pages not allowed as hyper-links on Stack Overflow?

Is it for browser compatibility concerns? Or is it perhaps for the same reason Stack Overflow disallows links to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) without code in the post?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with jQuery source links. This:

```
http://view-source:http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js
```

is not a valid URL, which is what the script is *actually* complaining about.

To actually view the source, you would use solely the `view-source` browser scheme, like so:

```
view-source:code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js
```

That URI scheme is not allowed on the network and will not even render as a link when used (only plain text). There's really no reason to allow it, as there's rarely ever a circumstance wherein it's actually useful to reference a live file somewhere on the web and point to a line number. In fact, I'm not entirely convinced it's even useful here. It'd probably be far better off to just extract a small section out of that file which contains the line you're referencing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the correct [view-source: URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View-source_URI_scheme) would be `view-source:http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js`. Yes, there's (effectively) a double scheme, because to view the source, the browser needs to know the scheme (`http`) of the original URI.

Comment: @Ilmari True, but most browsers nowadays chop off the http. You would have to includd it if it were https.

Comment: Is there any way to share page source links? Obviously `[text](view-source:{url})` doesn't work. I tried to share the page source links many times while answering [tag:web-scraping] questions.

Comment: @Keyur "That URI scheme is not allowed on the network". So no.